# Include spec_helper in Rakefile

Tags: rspec, rake, rake-task, rspec3

In Rspec 3, the preferred way to include the `spec/spec_helper.rb` file is to add a flag to the `.rpsec` file:

```
--require spec_helper
```

Which eliminates the need to add a reference at the top of each `_spec` files:

```
# include 'spec/spec_heler'  <-- removed

describe FooController do
end
```

However, when I attempt to run Rspec test via Rake, I get an error:

```
$ rake test
Traceback (most recent call last):
/Users/<user>/Projects/sinatra/mod/spec/app/controllers/foo_controller_spec.rb:1:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant FooController (NameError)
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1)

Tasks: TOP => test
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Which suggests that the `.rpsec` and `spec_helper` files are not being read.

The contents of the `Rakefile`:

```
require 'rake/testtask'

Rake::TestTask.new do |t|
  t.pattern = "spec/**/*_spec.rb"
end
```

The contents of the `spec/spec_helper.rb`:

```
require 'rack/test'
require 'rspec'

require File.expand_path '../../app.rb', __FILE__

RSpec.configure do |config|

  # rack
  config.include Rack::Test::Methods

  ...
end
```

How do I correct this problem?

Comment: You need to use a rake file that looks more like: https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/command-line/rake-task ; also if this is rails you want to really include `rails_helper` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to change the `Rakefile`:

```
require 'rspec/core/rake_task'

task :default => :spec

RSpec::Core::RakeTask.new(:spec) do |t|
  t.pattern = "spec/**/*_spec.rb"
end
```

I also needed to change the `spec/spec_helper.rb` file:

```
# added
require 'rubygems'
require 'bundler/setup'

# existing
require 'rack/test'
require 'rspec'

require File.expand_path '../../app.rb', __FILE__

RSpec.configure do |config|

  # rack
  config.include Rack::Test::Methods

  ...

end
```

When tests are run from `rspec`:

```
$ rspec
...
Finished in 0.07952 seconds (files took 0.63445 seconds to load)
15 examples, 0 failures, 1 pending
```

When tests are run from `rake`:

```
$ rake
/Users/<user>/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/bin/ruby -I/Users/<user>/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-support-3.8.0/lib:/Users/<user>/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.8.0/lib /Users/<user>/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.8.0/exe/rspec --pattern spec/\*\*/\*_spec.rb
...
Finished in 0.08885 seconds (files took 0.70133 seconds to load)
15 examples, 0 failures, 1 pending
```

Not sure why it adds the `$LOAD_PATH`, however.